# What is the alternative to using the Deprecated Hamcrest method is()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest

I use the following code at the moment to assert on a `boolean` value, however the method `org.hamcrest.Matchers.is()` is deprecated.

```
assertThat(someValue, is(false));
```

Is there a simple alternative syntax to test for boolean values without resorting to `assertTrue()` which gives you poor failure messages like "java.lang.AssertionError"

---

**Edit** after receiving comments/answers

My initial concerns were raised because Eclipse shows the following import statement as deprecated

[image]

On viewing the [Hamcrest API](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.2.1/hamcrest-library-1.2.1-javadoc.jar!/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) docs there are 3 overloaded variations of the `is()` method, only one of which is deprecated.

Therefore, to clarify the comment from @mark and the answer from @matt, the use of `is()` that I have posted above is valid and not deprecated.

Comment: It's not deprecated, I always prefer `is()` to `equalTo()` for booleans.  But they're aliases for each other.

Comment: You can include `*` instead of naming each matcher for brevity and to avoid the warning.

Comment: @David ...until you use "Organize Imports"

Comment: @Brad Set `Number of static imports needed for .*` to `1`.

Comment: Guys, is the conclusion here that it's a bug in Eclipse? I see this strikethrough all the time on the static import

Comment: No bug in Eclipse. See my comment to the accepted answer below. There are many overloaded methods named `is()` only some of which are deprecated

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have you tried `equalTo(T)`?

```
assertThat(someValue, equalTo(false));
```

I don't see that [`is(T)`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#is%28T%29) is deprecated - [is(Class) is deprecate](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#is%28java.lang.Class%29)d however.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You are right `is(T)` is not deprecated. I see that it's overloaded sibling `is(Class<T>)` is deprecated which was leading me to believe that all uses of `is()` were deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

I had thought this was a transitive dependency issue, but it's really just a display issue in Eclipse where it marks the import as deprecated because one overloaded form is. The code should compile fine since the import will expose all forms.

The deprecated form has been removed from the source and will not exist in the next release (1.4).

**Original Answer**

The problem is that [JUnit includes a set of Hamcrest classes in its JAR](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/issues/27). You can use `junit-dep.jar` for now, but newer versions (4.9 and 4.10 so far) of JUnit omit them.

Comment: That is a problem but how is it related to this question? I use junit-4.11 and I still get this. In hamcrest-1.3 all three methods mentioned exist. The one that is first in the order eclipse finds them is the deprecated one and AFAICT that is the one eclipse flags as deprecated. Interestingly it is placed below the others in the source file.

Comment: @aron I've updated my answer now that I see it's just an Eclipse display issue.

Answer (score 7):

This is deprecated:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

We can use this instead:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is said, use `instanceOf` for class matcher in the document.

http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/hamcrest/core/Is.html#isA(java.lang.Class)

```
is(IOException.class);
```

will be

```
is(instanceOf(IOException.class));
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in *Jan 2022*

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
```