# JUnit in Spring Tool Suite : Errors in running test

Tags: java, junit

I am running JUnit test for the first time and I get this error message.  How can I resolve it?

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Could not create test
>   'should_return_a_set_of_6_numbers_with_no_duplicates'     at
>   junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader$1.runTest(JUnit3TestLoader.java:177)
>     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)  at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)     at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)  at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Also when I import `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;`  the word `is` is striked out.  What other import can I use to replace it?

I am using STS version 3.6.4.

```
package net.javavideotutorials.assignment1;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Tests {


  @Test
  public void should_return_a_set_of_6_numbers_with_no_duplicates ()
  {
    LotteryNumberGenerator sut = new LotteryNumberGenerator();

    Set<Integer> lotteryNumbers = sut.generateLotteryNumbers();

    assertThat(lotteryNumbers.size(), is(6));
  }

}
```

Comment: This is way too little information. What code does your test have, what version(s) are you using? ...

Comment: Add your spring config file and show us your tests so the community can get a better understanding of why this is breaking.

Comment: This is Spring Tool Suite version 3.6.4.  Where can I find spring config file? Thanks. I just started learning this.

Comment: Looks like your test case is configured to use the (deprecated and incompatible) JUnit3 runner instead of JUnit4 by your IDE. Knowing this it should be easy to google for a fix (use "eclipse" in search term because STS is based on it). Your project doesn't seem to use Spring Framework so don't worry about "spring config": there isn't any. Hamcrest import not working looks like dependency mgmt problem: should also be easily googlable.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606196/what-is-the-alternative-to-using-the-deprecated-hamcrest-method-is) question, try `equalTo`:

```
assertThat(lotteryNumbers.size(), equalTo(6));
```